# How large are Linux system files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8.1, virtualbox, multi-boot

I'm looking to install Ubuntu (alongside pre-existing Win 8.1) but I'm wondering how much space is needed for the Ubuntu system file? cos right now I have only 20GBs left on my `C:\` partition..

Also would I be better off with a Ubuntu VM on virtualbox or a legit bootable one? (for like occasional or so using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer depends very much on which Linux distirbution you are using.

there are some very small distributions out there like Puppy Linux [(site link)](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) which claims to only need 100MB or some much larger ones (5GB ubuntu or more recommended, 10GB for mint)
[(source for ubuntu install size)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) - [(Source for Mint install size)](http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/view/1775-what-is-the-hardware-requirements-for-linux-mint)

On top of this, there will be applications, files etc that you will want to install, space needed for updates etc - so you will need a fair chunk of space for most editions of Linux.

---

As for dual boot vs VM vs Live Disk:

**Dual boot** will give you best performance.  100% system resources can be dedicated to a dual booted Linux, but when running a VM - there will always be the overhead of the parent operating system (windows) and the hypervisor (vmware, hyperv, virtualbox etc).  Dual booting can come with greater risk as damaging your boot partition may make neither operating system useable without some serious repair work.

**VM** will give you more flexibility to hop between operating systems at a minutes notice without having to shutdown.  It also gives you functionality to pause Linux to give windows it's power back or vice versa.  It also comes with some nice tools like snapshotting which will make undoing mistakes a lot easier.  Thsi does come with the caveat that it will never be as powerful as a full OS.

**Live Disk** can be the worst of both or the best of both.  If you have a fast USB3 drive, you can get fast access to your storage, dedicate all your resources to an instance and still reboot to windows with no issues while avoiding the risks of setting up a dual boot.  On the other hand, if you are limited to CD/USB1/USB2 - you get limited by storage speeds.  Regardless of your storage speed, you still have to shutdown/suspend windows to boot to your live disk meaning you need to save all your work and stick to one OS at a time.  You also lose the VM snapshot functionality whcih is only present on a VM.

It depends entirely on your use case - but if you are evaluating and picking an OS - I'd recommend a VM to begin with while you make up your mind - followed by installing your pick of OS as a primary OS and then dual boot to your secondary choise of OS.

If you do decide to dual boot, I would very much recommend you use GRUB as your bootloader.  I have windows 10, Ubuntu and mint all installed on the same laptop at the minute and my wife has a windows 7 & ubuntu setup for her laptop as well - both booting through GRUB and no problems whatsoever (yet, 2 years in)

Comment: well i'm in my first year in computer & networking (vocational school) and looking to get a headstart and get myself used to linux environment bcs we'll be using linux-based OS on the second year and also apparently no GUI allowed :|

Comment: and how big is the margin of performance between the VM and the bootable one?

Comment: depends on the spec of your hardware.  If you have a high end PC - you may well be able to dedicate a lot of resource and there may be little difference.  If your PC is slow, bootable will be much faster  If you work with a bootable pendrive - it is limited by the speed of your media (CD, DVD, USB) and so a VM may be faster

Answer (score 0):

The installed size of a Linux distribution really depends on which one it is.  There is the minimum such as [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) or Damn Small Linux (website currently not loading).  However the package selections of those are limited - the usual bases are covered but they don't have something like Debian's 40k+ packages.  A good balance between many packages and also as small as possible installation size is [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/).  Arch is what you make it.  You can install as much or as little as you need, however it does require at least a familiarity with Linux in general or you will face more challenges.

With many Linux distributions there are many resulting installation sizes depending on what each includes as a default.  Besides the ones already given searching will likely turn up more candidates.

Running in a VM will always be slower than running on the bare metal.  However, running a VM will allow you to try many more things with little risk.  If you are just beginning with Linux then starting in a VM until you have the basics understood wouldn't be bad, then once you've been around the block install on the bare metal for performance.

Comment: oops i forgot to add this.. it's ubuntu that i'm going to be using

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using a Virtual Machine because :

- No problems with dual-boot.
- It can begin on short space and then grow it up in function of your needs.
- If you are unhappy with the chosen distribution and delete the VM, everything keeps working fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In my old (1998 vintage) laptop, I was running Win98 dual booted with antiX (Debian based lightweight distro) on a 16 GB Compact Flash in an IDE adapter (emulating an SSD).  Windows had 6 GB, antiX had 8 plus a 2 GB swap space (machine had 768 MB RAM).  Worked fine, even on a single core at 300 MHz.

As noted, if you choose a light distro, you can run Linux in as little as about 4 GB of space; even Ubuntu will run okay in 20 GB, if you don't download or install too much "stuff".